# Why i am getting undefined in the output along with the answer?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```
let array = [1, 2, 3];
function lastElement(array) 
{

    if (array === []) 
    {
        return null;
    }
    else 
    {
        return array.slice(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call this? Why don't you just call `array.slice(-1)` instead of this function?

Comment: Can you show what you got in the output

Comment: i had a question where i had to print the last element of the array and if array is empty then null should be printed... i am freaking confused .. pls help !!!!! ... do i need to declare array in the begining??? like i did in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are doing it in the wrong way, you cannot check if an array is empty like you did.

```
function lastElement(array) {
  if(array.length == 0) return null
  return array[array.length - 1]
}
```

`array.length` returns the count of elements inside an array.

You also need not to add an else statement because if we are returning from a functions, the code below that line does not get executed.

Comment: thanks Vikas ... Solved my problem. its just that i am a much beginner to coding and get stuck at small problems and loose hope wasting my whole time at these small problem

Answer (score 1):

**Hi I seen you are facing the issue of checking array and slice the data also.**

*Simply if you want to check the array is empty or not you will using something like this in the js*

**To get the last element of an array you can use**

```js
let array = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(array.length-1);
```

**To Check array is empty and also get the last element of an array**

```js
 let array = [1, 2, 3];
function lastElement(array) {
  if(array.length == 0) return null
  return array[array.length - 1]
}

console.log(lastElement(array))
```

[To know more about slice which you have used in the above problem click here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp)